# Input Mismatch Exception Error,

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Program compiles and runs perfectly until I try to execute my load method in main. Program crashes and gives me an input mismatch exception at 
part number = scan.nextInt(); ..... Anyone know why?

```
public static InventoryManager load(String fileName) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException
{
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
    Scanner stringScan;
    InventoryManager StockChart = new InventoryManager();

   // Part variables
   String record = "";
   int partNumber=0;
   String description="";
   int qty=0; 
   double cost = 0.00; 


  while(fileScan.hasNext())
  {
     record = fileScan.nextLine();
     stringScan = new Scanner (record);
     stringScan.useDelimiter("  ");     //allows for separation when reading 
     partNumber = stringScan.nextInt(); // scans part number
     description = stringScan.next();   // scans description 
     qty = stringScan.nextInt();        // scans the qty on hand 
     cost = stringScan.nextDouble();    // scans the item cost 

     //create new part object for each line in file 
     StockChart.addStock(new Stock(partNumber,description, qty,cost)); 

  }


    return StockChart; // return new list back to InventoryClerk program 
}
```

Text File is formatted as follows (disregard spaces in between):

1117[tab]1/2-13 FHN[tab]450[tab]6.11

1118[tab]1/2-13 FHN[tab]100[tab]0.23

1119[tab]1/2-13 FHN[tab]100[tab]4.11

Comment: You missed a `.next()`. You are getting: `nextInt: 1117`, `next: 1/2-13`, `nextInt: FHN` (error). Also, why is your delimiter 2 spaces?

Comment: I understand what you're saying but shouldn't the delimiter scan 1/2 -13 FHN as the whole description because then it tabs to 450 which is an int? I apologize for the way the file looks as its hard to tell what is a tab and what is a space

Comment: _Oh_, I see. You should [edit] your post to show where you have tabs instead of spaces, as it is very hard to tell right now. You could, for example, add `[tab]` to where you have tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: There we go looks a little clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way rather than using the `stringScan` Scanner object is to simply to use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) on the `record` String

e.g.

```
while(fileScan.hasNext())
{
   record = fileScan.nextLine();
   String el[] = record.split (" ");
   partNumber = Integer.parseInt (el[0]);
   description = el[1];
   // etc
```

Comment: How would I do the description part of it is where I'm confused (I added the qty and cost portion following your idea which makes much more sense)

Comment: `description` is simply `el[1]`

Comment: I have that part for everything the only thing is how would I parse it though is what I am asking specifically (hence no String.parseString)

Comment: Perfect! Thank You so much!